# No choice Windows Boot Menu

Tags: dual-boot

I'm dualbooting Ubuntu 15.10 W.W. alongside Windows 7. I did a stupid thing and set the Windows Boot Menu timer to 0. So now whenever I boot, it doesn't give me a choice, it just boots to Ubuntu. Because of that, I cant even access the startup tools or anything associated to Windows. Plz help.

Comment: Hold or rapidly tap F8. That should bring you to the advanced menu where you can enter Safe Mode and fix the time.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the value of `timeout` in your `boot.ini` file.

Comment: I think, `boot.ini` doesn't exist on Windows 7 anymore

Comment: In the grub menu, it only shows Ubuntu and Advanced options for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

From Ubuntu, I think you couldn't do something. So I give you two options:

- Since `boot.ini` don't exist in Windows 7, you could obtain a Windows 7 Recovery image and try to execute the tool `bcdedit`. [See the last comment](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1181105) from this entry on Ubuntu Forum (he did it for a Vista, but should be the same).
- The other is to use GRUB instead the Windows 7 boot manager. Probably, with `GParted` you could change the boot partition to the Ubuntu boot partition. But before, try to configure GRUB with the command `sudo update-grub`. ([More info](http://www.howtogeek.com/196655/how-to-configure-the-grub2-boot-loaders-settings/))

Hope this helps and fix the issue.

Comment: Thx for the advice, I just factory reset my computer and everything is working just fine.